# Must the defendant be addressed by the prosecution during trial by their chosen name?

Tags: united-states, florida

There are many forms of a name, some of them are informal, some are more formal than what is used commonly.

For example, with the name William, there's William itself, Will, Billy, etc.

If the prosecution insisted on addressing the defendant with a specific name form that was not the defendant's chosen form of address, would the defence be able to object to it?

For example, if the prosecutor decided to refer to someone calls himself Will during the trial, would calling him William or Billy be objectionable at all, and the form "Will" be forced for future references?

Comment: Mr Surname is the usual form. First names are not used.

Comment: Regardless of rules, being disrespectful to other people in the court doesn't set a good impression with the judge or jury, so there's strong incentive against it.